# Why do I get a warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]

Tags: c, compiler-errors, assignment-operator, comparison-operators

I have to print a Christmas tree, this is the code for the trunk:"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {

    int j;
    int cspaziodx,cspaziosx,cltroncoo;  
    float cltronco,larghezza;

    printf ("ins larghezza");
    scanf ("%f",&larghezza);

    for (j=1;j<=(ceil(larghezza/10));j++) {

    cltronco = roundf(larghezza/4);
    cltroncoo = cltronco;
    if (cltroncoo%2==0) {(cltroncoo == cltroncoo + 1);}
    cspaziodx = ((larghezza - cltroncoo)/2);
    cspaziosx = ((larghezza -  cltroncoo)/2);

            while (cspaziodx > 0) 
                {
                printf(" ");
                cspaziodx = cspaziodx - 1;
                }
                while (cltroncoo > 0)
                    {
                    printf ("|");
                    cltroncoo = cltroncoo - 1;  
                    }

                    while (cspaziodx > 0) 
                        {
                        printf(" ");
                        cspaziosx = cspaziosx - 1;
                        }                   

    printf ("\n");

    }

    return 0;
    }
```

"

and the error is in this line `if (cltroncoo%2==0) {(cltroncoo == cltroncoo + 1);}`
why does not work?

Comment: `==` is comparison, not assignment; simply comparing two values has no effect :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with

```
(cltroncoo == cltroncoo + 1)
```

which uses the comparison operator `==`. Maybe what you meant is

```
(cltroncoo = cltroncoo + 1)
```

where we use the assignment operator `=`.

Just to add some clarity, for the equality operator, `==`, as per `C11` spec, chapter §6.5.9,

> [...] Each of the operators yields 1 if the
>   specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. The result has type `int`. For any pair of
>   operands, exactly one of the relations is true.

Now, in your case, you missed to use the *result*, so your compiler screams.

Also, FWIW, instead of `int main ()`, you should use `int main (void)`, atleast.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (cltroncoo%2==0) {                        // comapre
     (cltroncoo == cltroncoo + 1);            // again compare ??
 }
```

In body of `if` you use `==` (*will just compare both value*), maybe you intended to use `=` *assignment operator* to change value of variable.

```
(cltroncoo =cltroncoo + 1);
```